# How to get current logged in user in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

just wondering how to access the data of a logged in authenticated user in a react js file with node js.

In the handlebar files I have I can see information like this:
`{{#if user}}`

I would like to know how to do things like that in a react js file so I can assign the name of the logged in user to a js variable. Something like 
`var name = {{# user.name }};`

Thanks in advance and sorry if I've missed something out or said something a tad dense.

Comment: React isn't a full framework, so there's nothing built in for checking if a user exists or is logged in you have to build that yourself, or find a library that provides that.

Comment: did you find any solution..?

Comment: Kinda, I added the users id to the page and got it by using a get elementById in the react code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to use a method for authentication, JWT is a good bet to do so. then in your main component (`app.js`) send a request to a specific route (like `/auth/init`) to check if the user is logged (means jwt is set).

you can approach this using middlewares if you are using `express.js`. if the user was logged in then send the user's credentials back to the client (react) and initialize your `user` state with the response.

To share user state between your components you have different options. based on your needs you can choose from `redux`, `contextAPI`, or just newly introduced API `hooks`. read [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/state-management-with-react-hooks-no-redux-or-context-api-8b3035ceecf8) for further perspective.