# How to get windows current logged on user in react

Tags: reactjs, iis, windows-authentication

I want to know which Windows authenticated logged on user use my site, how would I do it?
in .net I used the line of code

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

How would I do it in ReactJS?
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current logged in user in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248417/how-to-get-current-logged-in-user-in-react-js)

Comment: I think thats impossible to get login name of users OS from website app.

Comment: While user login successfully in server side, you can use .net code to store the user in cookie and send to client. Then reactJS get user from cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly get the Windows username in ReactJS, it would be a security risk if you could.
Check out this answer for more details: [How to get the name of the current Windows user in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-windows-user-in-javascript)